# JSF list of different elements

Tags: jsf

I have an entity called Garage that has some properties and a list of Vehicles.
Vehicle is inherited by some entities like Car, Truck, Bike, etc.

I want to make a JSF page to create a Garage, that allows the user to add, remove and edit the list of Vehicles.

I tried to use a DataTable to list the Vehicles, but Car, Truck, Bike, etc have different attributes so each should display different fields.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This answer I hope will help you. [PrimeFaces dataTable with variable columns and specific editable cells](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30240735/8053244)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I need. I need only one column that displays a different Composite Component for each Vehicle, or something la that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display two different types of components based on a boolean variable in jsf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134515/how-to-display-two-different-types-of-components-based-on-a-boolean-variable-in)

Comment: The boolean here can (should?) be an instanceof comparison

Comment: Thanks Selaron, that would work, but the JSF should know all the posible instances of Vehicle. I am looking for something more generic if its possible, maybe a way to call the instances composite component based on some attribute. Probably, I'll create a composite component that knows all the Vehicle instances and choses the right cc for the instance.